# Как отправить личное сообщение в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я хочу чтобы при бане и разбане человеку отправлялось личное сообщение с уведомлением о бане.

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} **забанен** \n Продолжительность бана: *{time}d* \n Причина бана: *{reason}*')
  #отправить пользователю личное сообщение о бане "Тебя забанили на сервере {server} по причине {reason}
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  await asyncio.sleep(time * 86400)
  await member.unban()
  await ctx.send(f'*У {member.mention} закончился бан*')
  #отправить пользователю личное сообщение о разбане "У тебя закончился бан на сервере {server} <ссылка на сервер>; Тебя разбанили на сервере {server} <ссылка на сервер>
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У объекта [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.send) есть метод `send`

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} **забанен** \n Продолжительность бана: *{time}d* \n Причина бана: *{reason}*')
    #отправить пользователю личное сообщение о бане "Тебя забанили на сервере {server} по причине {reason}
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 86400)
    await member.unban()
    await ctx.send(f'*У {member.mention} закончился бан*')
    #отправить пользователю личное сообщение о разбане "У тебя закончился бан на сервере {server} <ссылка на сервер>; Тебя разбанили на сервере {server} <ссылка на сервер>
    await member.send('text')
```